# c++ how to iterate over a collection of objects w/o explicitly created iterate-able container

Tags: c++

i would like to loop over a fixed number of objects (all of the same type) without having to first explicitly create an iterate-able container with those objects as members, for example:

```
object_type a, b, c; 
// do sth with objects a, b, c

for (auto &x in {a, b, c}) 
{ // do }; // wish: be able to loop over objects via on-the-fly-container {a, b, c}
```

questions:

1. how can i implement the kind of loop in the example in the most succinct/elegant fashion?
2. generally, with same-type members: can one create implicitly defined vectors? tuples? any container at all?

thanks

Comment: Do you also want to be able to modify the objects in the loop?

Comment: @cigien, not actually needed, but i guess referencing may be more efficient with large objects?

Comment: Sure, it's definitely more efficient, but note that the loop variable is *not* a reference to the actual objects.

Comment: @cigien, ah, because those objects are already _copied_ into the {a,b,c}?

Comment: @cigien Not sure it's necessarily more efficient. If the compiler can figure out to avoid the copy, the indirection through the reference may actually be (mildly) worse.

Comment: @bitmask Hmm, are you sure it could actually be *worse* to use `&`? Seems like compilers would do the right thing there.

Comment: Added a version that modifies the objects as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just iterate over an initializer list containing the objects:

```
for(auto o : {a, b, c})
  // ...
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EcW7Gn).

You could also write `auto &o`, but note that `o` is *not* a reference to the actual objects `a`, `b`, and `c`, so you won't be able to modify them. If you want to do that, you could write it this way:

```
for(auto *o : {&a, &b, &c})
   // *o is the object
```

where you iterate over the addresses of the objects.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/54eYYW).

Comment: Regarding writing to the reference. C++ actually enforces a constant reference at that point. So `for (auto& x: {y}) x = z;` **will** produce a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got the [for-each loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) right:

```
for (auto& x: {a, b, c}) {
}
```

You can turn this expression into a vector as well:

```
auto stuff = std::vector<object_type>{a, b, c};
```

And since C++17 you can even have C++ infer the type of the vector:

```
auto stuff = std::vector{a, b, c};
```